# Scrolling image in block

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can i create scrolling image in display notebook with overflow notebook?
Try with sticky notebook, but notebook image with shadow, and bg image doesnt overflowed.

I want it to stay background img inside the screen, but it doesn't work.
Top point bg on top notebook when its reveals.
Maybe some one have examples?

```css
.project-rules__note {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  padding-top: 600px;
  }
.project-rules__note  > img {
    width: 53vw;
    height: auto;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
  }
.project-rules__note  .container {
    width: 68vw;
    height: 100vh;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
   

  }
.project-rules__note  .note {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 100px;
    }

 .project-rules__note   .bg-note {
      width: 68vw;
      height: auto;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
      top: 0;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, 0);
      }

.project-rules__note      .bg-note::before {

      }

.project-rules__note     .bg-note img {
        width: 100%;
      }
    

 .project-rules__note   .book {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      display: flex;
      align-items: flex-end;
      justify-content: flex-start;


      z-index: 2;
      }

.project-rules__note .book     img {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        max-height: 100vh;
      }
```

```html
<div class="project-rules__note">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="note">
                    <div class="img book">
                        <img src="https://jukachu.github.io/Lottery-cards/src/notebook.png" alt="">
                    </div>
<!--                    <div class="img bg-note">-->
<!--                        <img src="./img/bgnote.jpg" alt="">-->
<!--                    </div>-->
                </div>
            </div>
            <img src="https://i.ibb.co/74d27jf/bgnote.jpg" alt="">

        </div>
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you want, can you more explain

Comment: When notebook picture comes up, bg alredy on top point of notebook, and its stick on top 0 viewport and scroll only bg image. And bg image overflow by screen of notebook